# Convert json array to json object in service in angular 2+

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have a service that gets the result in an API. API returns the results as JSON array. But I need the result as JSON object.

API returns:

```
[{"record_id":"101","demographics_spring_complete":"2"}]
```

I need as object format:

```
{"record_id":"101","demographics_spring_complete":"2"}
```

My service.ts:

```
getStatus() {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl).map(res => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

And my conponent.ts:

```
export class BaselineListComponent implements OnInit {  
statuses: any[] = []; 

constructor(
   public recordService: RecordsService
 ) { }

 loadStatus() {
    this.recordService.getStatus('demographic_spring', 'baseline_visit_a_arm_1', 101).subscribe(statuses => {
  this.statuses = statuses;
  console.log(this.statuses);
   });
  }
}
```

I did try some conversion options but since API returns an array, I am unable to convert them to a JSON object. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need the first Object of the array, use array[index] as follows,

```
loadStatus() {
    this.recordService.getStatus('demographic_spring', 'baseline_visit_a_arm_1', 101).subscribe(statuses => {
     this.statuses = statuses;
     console.log(this.statuses[0]);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `do` operator and return the first element.

```
getStatus() {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl).map(res => res.json())
        .do(res => res[0])
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: That still gives me as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Create model class (record.model.js)

```
export class Record {
   constructor(
    record_id: string,
    demographics_spring_complete : string,
   ){}
}
```

At Service.js Class You need to code like this:

Import some Library at Service.js class

```
import { Record } from '../models/record.model'
import 'rxjs'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'
```

create the functions to get the record

```
   getRecords(): Observable<Record[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.userApiUrl)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error'))
  }
```

In the component.ts file Add global variable:

```
record: Record;
```

then subcribe the record function of service

```
getRecord(): void {
 this.recordService.getRecords().subscribe((result: any) => {
    this.record = result && result[0] || {};
 }, (error: any) => {
   console.log(error);
 });
}
```

if the `result` return `[{"record_id":"101","demographics_spring_complete":"2"}]`, result[0] will return `{"record_id":"101","demographics_spring_complete":"2"}`, but if the result has not value `undefiend` execption will be occured, we will use `this.record = result && result[0] || {};` to handled the execption.